# Image load  by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

We have image and links in separate blocks.

When link is clicked, its `href` attribute puts to `src` of the image.

What I'm trying to do:

```
If image is not already loaded (not cached) {
    fadeOut previous image {
        fadeIn loader {
            load image (when animation of loader ends) {
                fadeOut loader {
                    fadeIn image
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else (if image is cached, do not show loader) {
    fadeOut previous image {
        fadeIn new image
    }
}
```

Here is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/EvXJr/13/

First part works, don't know how to code the second (`else`) part.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dirty way would be to assign ids to loaded images, if there is no element with such id on a page - show loader, else just animate image.

Example:
html:

```
<div id="container">
   <a href="http://www.site.com/image.png" id="smid1"></a>
   <a href="http://www.site.com/image.png" id="smid2"></a>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#container').delegate('a', 'click', function () {
   var sel_id = this.id;
   if (!document.getElementById('img_' + this.id)) {
      //create image with  id  like: sel_id = 'img_' + this.id
   } else {
      //just show image
   }
});
```

Comment: i'd do this like that. generate a elements with ids attributes <a id="sm_id_1" href="http://site.com/image.png"></a>  and assign ids like "img_sm_id_1" to image linked

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get the jsfiddle to load but if I understand correctly I would just set the background image of the element that holds the images to a loading gif then you don't have to worry about fading in and out a loader. If an image is already cached it will load so quickly you will never see the loading gif. And if it isn't and takes a while to load the user will see the loading gif and using the function below the image will fade in nicely once loaded.

And if you want to perform a function once an image has loaded use

```
$("img").load(function(){
    //do stuff once image has loaded.
    //for example
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: loader is not a background, it is a separate block, far away from the image holder. Code on jsfiddle is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just keep track of what HREFs you have loaded with a javascript array that you have loaded and if your HREF can be found in the loaded array just take out the loader related functions.